# How to convert FileEntry to standard JavaScript File object using chrome apps fileSystem

Tags: javascript, filesystems, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to convert `FileEntry` to standard JavaScript object `File`?
I can't find anything meaningful in documentation https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `FileEntry` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry) does provide guidance here:

> The `FileSystemFileEntry` interface of the File System API represents a
> file in a file system. It offers properties describing the file's
> attributes, as well as the `file()` method, which creates a File object
> that can be used to read the file.

Unfortunately `file()`method relies on callbacks rather Promises, but we can wrap that and make using the API (and reading the code) easier:

```js
async function getFile(fileEntry) {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fileEntry.file(resolve, reject));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// From inside an async method or JS module
let file = await getFile(fileEntry); // Wait until we have the file
```

Comment: Hi, I was curious why you used async and await when defining `getFile`. Would it not work the same if you got rid of them, and just returned the promise directly?

Comment: @ack_inc yes you're right, it doesn't add anything, thanks for picking that up. Edited per your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I found how to do this in google examples https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/filesystem-access/js/app.js

```
var jsFileObject;
fileEntry.file(function (file){ 
   jsFileObject = file 
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the error callback! You will silently never get a callback in some (albeit) rare cases. The signature should be `entry.file(success,error)`

Comment: Take note that this code is asynchronous: you can't immediately use `jsFileObject`. See xlm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113059/934239) for a Promise-based solution to that problem.